# Make material thick around edges

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, shaders, lighting

I want to make the material in the provided .blend to be like the provided image. .blend https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZDs_sCikX-TMTRcuNTmoQeKwBAvsabfk [image: Like in the circled part]

[image: my current node setup]

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1VjB.png)?

Comment: no, that has kind of a hard outline I'm looking for something that blends in

Comment: Can you post an image that shows the topology of the object and the node settings you currently have?

Comment: I have added my node setup

Comment: @TechCrate nah that its the fresnel effect, and it looks appropiate the node settings so if you want thickness add it in the mesh.

Comment: I actually figured it out

Comment: ok, I will do that

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution that I came up with:

1: These nodes are a fresnel node with other nodes to disperse it

2. The second group is a color ramp to blend in the fresnel to the rest of the material
3. This is a mix shader to add it to the rest of the material[image: the new nodes]

Comment: I'm confused: In number 3, why are you using a mix shader with a disconnected socket?

Comment: to input the factor for the fresnel node

Comment: with a non-shader? Black?

Comment: see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134731/change-color-of-fresnel-node