# Change color of fresnel node

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor

I want to have a white outline and not a black one like the fresnel node makes[image: here is my node setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused on how the mix shader works.

It has two inputs for shaders and one for the factor of the mix.

If one of the shader inputs is not connected to anything, you are using the fact to mix to a non-shader (or just black).

[image]

[image]